# How to initialize a new variable in an existing model in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am calling an api and it returns a json data and this data i embedding with the model by using online converter. Below is the sample json data and model

> JSON

```
{
    "message": "menues returned by Dish Type successfully",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

> Model

```
class DishMenuTypesIdData {
  String? id;
  DishMenuTypesIdData({
    this.id,
  });
  DishMenuTypesIdData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    return data;
  }
}
class DishMenuTypesId {
  String? message;
  List<DishMenuTypesIdData?>? data;
  DishMenuTypesId({
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });
  DishMenuTypesId.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json["message"]?.toString();
  if (json["data"] != null) {
  final v = json["data"];
  final arr0 = <DishMenuTypesIdData>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(DishMenuTypesIdData.fromJson(v));
  });
    this.data = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["message"] = message;
    if (this.data != null) {
      final v = this.data;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["data"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now i decided to add a variable `qty` and initialize `qty` in existing model which will be

```
int qty;
```

And in constructor it will be

```
this.qty = 1;
```

But when i call this qty in ui then it is getting `null`. Although i initialize this qty in constructor equals `1`

> Model After including qty

```
class DishMenuTypesIdData {

  String? qty;
  String? id;

  DishMenuTypesIdData({
    this.qty = "1",
    this.id,
  });
  DishMenuTypesIdData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    qty = json["qty"]?.toString();
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["qty"] = qty;
    data["id"] = id;
    return data;
  }
}

class DishMenuTypesId {

  String? message;
  List<DishMenuTypesIdData?>? data;

  DishMenuTypesId({
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });
  DishMenuTypesId.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json["message"]?.toString();
  if (json["data"] != null) {
  final v = json["data"];
  final arr0 = <DishMenuTypesIdData>[];
  v.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(DishMenuTypesIdData.fromJson(v));
  });
    this.data = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["message"] = message;
    if (this.data != null) {
      final v = this.data;
      final arr0 = [];
  v!.forEach((v) {
  arr0.add(v!.toJson());
  });
      data["data"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you mark/include the part how you are adding `qty` variable?  I can't find it on code-snippet.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have updated the code, kindly check it.

Comment: If I'm not wrong , JSON methods are missing `qty`, can you include those on `fromJson` and `toJson()`? and make sure to change the type on `String? qty;` while you are passing an int.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Added `fromJson` and `toJson`

Comment: do you still get errors?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh In UI (main.dart) it is getting `null`

Comment: how did you create model? is it on onTap or FutureBuilder?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it is `onTap`.

Comment: can you include that `onTap` method inside question?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the code is very lengthy, i have checked in debugging `qty = null`. If you want that `dart page` then i can share you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is not returning the qty when being called, thus the qty will be null.

```
qty = json["qty"]?.toString();
```

if you want to initialize it to 1, you need to replace this line with:

```
qty = "1";
```